# How to properly use consult-ripgrep to search through org-roam notes

Tags: doom, org-roam, consult, ripgrep

I am trying to setup a way to systematically search through all my org-roam notes and I came across the following code that uses consult-ripgrep:

```
(defun bms/org-roam-rg-search ()
  "Search org-roam directory using consult-ripgrep. With live-preview."
  (interactive)
  (let ((consult-ripgrep-command "rg --multiline --null --ignore-case --type org --line-buffered --color=always --max-columns=500 --no-heading --line-number . -e ARG OPTS"))
    (consult-ripgrep org-roam-directory)))
```

I am using doom emacs and I setup the above code in my `config.el` file. However, when I run `M-x bms/org-roam-rg-search` and type in anything, it asks me about 'matched required' as shown:
[image]

I am confused about what I am doing incorrect as it is searching the correct folder where my notes are stored and I am typing in keywords that exist in the directory but nothing shows up. When I open an eshell terminal and type `rg test` I get several matches but `consult-ripgrep` asking me for match required even though I typed in a string.

Comment: Your function works on my side.

Answer (score 2):

So I looked at the consul-ripgrep and consul-grep documentation and I'm still not entirely sure how the INITIAL parameter is meant to be used however I took your code and just added an empty string as the last parameter to the call to consult-ripgrep and it seems to be working now:

```
(defun local/org-roam-rg-search ()
  "Search org-roam directory using consult-ripgrep. With live-preview."
  (interactive)
  (let ((consult-ripgrep-command "rg --multiline --null --ignore-case --type org --line-buffered --color=always --max-columns=500 --no-heading --line-number . -e ARG OPTS"))
  (consult-ripgrep org-roam-directory "")))
```

Comment: I made the change as you did and I still get the same issue as above. Now that I look closely, when I type `M-x consult-ripgrep-command` nothing shows up. But `M-x consult-ripgrep` does show up.

Comment: The "initial" parameter for when you want to pre-populate the minibuffer with some search text. Useful when you already know some of what the query will contain, etc.

Comment: @mtraceur I guess that could be pre-populated with already selected text in the buffer, or word (or symbol) under a cursor if nothing else is selected?

Comment: @Daniel Yep. Another example is resuming search: for example, I have a [`consult-line-resume` command](https://github.com/mentalisttraceur/home/blob/8031f5f3a931f3c97d80fcd7656eab0cb6e54631/.emacs.el#L1461-L1479) which re-runs `consult-line` with the `initial` argument populated from `consult-line--history` (the latest search by default, or nth search (not counting older duplicates) with a numeric prefix argument, or go recursive with a `completing-read` to pick from the history with a non-numeric prefix argument).

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to setup a way to systematically search through all my org-roam notes ... I am using doom emacs

Doom's built-in function `+default/org-notes-search` does exactly this. It is bound to `SPC n s` (when using evil).